# ZPL/Zebra Printer not catching new line?

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I am passing a ZPL code to a Zebra printer. And in this ZPL code, I have a portion where it will generate a QR Code. The QR Code's value is from string that I got from using a barcode scanning function in the mobile app im developing for WM6.5.
The string result from the scan looks like this:
Name:John Smith
Gender:Male
Position:Developer

I need to pass this string to a datagrid. So I parse it line by line via "\n" or environment new line. passing it to the datagrid is ok. But when I print out the string result to a QR Code on a Zebra printer. It seems like the new lines are not being included in the QR Code.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to pass in non-printable characters, use the `^FH` command to pass it in as a hex value

```
^XA
^FO100,100
^AD^FH
^FDTilde _7e used for hex^FS
^XZ
```

This will print out a `~` instead of _7e

Comment: This should be marked as the answer.  I had trouble adding carriage returns and tabs to a QR code I was generating in ZPL and this solved it for me!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[ISO-8859-1 encoding characters](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~stolfi/EXPORT/www/ISO-8859-1-Encoding.html)

```
HTML     OCTL   HEX   CMP   CHR   MEANING
------ + ---- + --- + --- + --- + ------------------------------
&#010; | \012 | =0A |     |     | Line feed (ASCII NL, newline)
```

Use `0x0A` instead of `\n` ?